# equivalent of remove_if in D

Tags: c++, algorithm, d, idioms, phobos

Recently I have taken an interest in the D programming language. I just started learning it, and am coming from a C++ background. I am wondering if there is an equivalent of std::remove_if. I only saw remove looking through docs on the dlang site.
If there isn't a direct equivalent, what is the proper or most idiomatic way of achieving the same result in D?
edit: I should add that I am thinking in the context of erase-remove

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is [`std.algortihm.remove(pred,Range)(Range)`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#remove) (look a bit further down the page) which does what you ask

Comment: ah, I should have payed closer attention to the docs. thanks :)